# Why does my Spark Streaming application shut down immediately (and not process any Kafka records)?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I've created a Spark application in Python following the example described in [Spark Streaming + Kafka Integration Guide (Kafka broker version 0.8.2.1 or higher)](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-kafka-0-8-integration.html) to stream Kafka messages using Apache Spark, but it's shutting down before I get the chance to send any messages.

This is where the shutdown section begins in the output.

```
16/11/26 17:11:06 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Registered BlockManager BlockManagerId(driver, 1********6, 58045)
16/11/26 17:11:06 INFO VerifiableProperties: Verifying properties
16/11/26 17:11:06 INFO VerifiableProperties: Property group.id is overridden to 
16/11/26 17:11:06 INFO VerifiableProperties: Property zookeeper.connect is overridden to 
16/11/26 17:11:07 INFO SparkContext: Invoking stop() from shutdown hook
16/11/26 17:11:07 INFO SparkUI: Stopped Spark web UI at http://192.168.1.16:4040
16/11/26 17:11:07 INFO MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint: MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint stopped!
16/11/26 17:11:07 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore cleared
16/11/26 17:11:07 INFO BlockManager: BlockManager stopped
16/11/26 17:11:07 INFO BlockManagerMaster: BlockManagerMaster stopped
16/11/26 17:11:07 INFO OutputCommitCoordinator$OutputCommitCoordinatorEndpoint: OutputCommitCoordinator stopped!
16/11/26 17:11:07 INFO SparkContext: Successfully stopped SparkContext
16/11/26 17:11:07 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
16/11/26 17:11:07 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /private/var/folders/yn/t3pvrk7s231_11ff2lqr4jhr0000gn/T/spark-1876feee-9b71-413e-a505-99c414aafabf/pyspark-1d97c3dd-0889-42ed-b559-d0fd473faa22
16/11/26 17:11:07 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /private/var/folders/yn/t3pvrk7s231_11ff2lqr4jhr0000gn/T/spark-1876feee-9b71-413e-a505-99c414aafabf
```

Is there a way I should tell it to wait or am I missing something?

Full code:

```
from pyspark.streaming.kafka import KafkaUtils
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext

sc = SparkContext("local[2]", "TwitterWordCount")
ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 1)

directKafkaStream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(ssc, ["next"], {"metadata.broker.list": "localhost:9092"})

offsetRanges = []

def storeOffsetRanges(rdd):
    global offsetRanges
    offsetRanges = rdd.offsetRanges()
    return rdd

def printOffsetRanges(rdd):
    for o in offsetRanges:
        print("Printing! %s %s %s %s" % o.topic, o.partition, o.fromOffset, o.untilOffset)

directKafkaStream\
    .transform(storeOffsetRanges)\
    .foreachRDD(printOffsetRanges)
```

And here's the command to run it in case that's helpful.

```
spark-submit --packages org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kafka-0-8_2.11:2.0.2 producer.py
```

Answer (score 1):

You will also need to start the streaming context. Take a look at this example. 
http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#a-quick-example

```
ssc.start()             # Start the computation
ssc.awaitTermination()  # Wait for the computation to terminate
```

Answer (score 0):

For Scala when submitting to yarn with cluster mode I had to use awaitAnyTermination:

```
query.start()
sparkSession.streams.awaitAnyTermination()
```

as (kind of) per the docs here [Structured Streaming Guide](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html) half way through Quick Example.